# Can we use google cloud function to copy files from one project to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a requirement to write a cloud-function which will copy files from one project to another project. Can we use Google Cloud Function to do the same ? Can I use the destination_bucket from another project and source bucket from another project?

For example:

```
 blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )
```

Comment: Why could you not? It's only a matter of permissions!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible. You need to make sure the Service Account has access to both buckets (on both destination and source projects) and also have the necessary storage permissions (at least list, get, create).

You can review the roles here: [Cloud Storage roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

Comment: Thanks !! Let me try that.